# DevExpress XtraGrid bound to List<T> : how to show change in data immediately in the GUI?

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

I have an XtraGrid and a VerticalGrid on the form. Both are bound to the same `List<T>`.

The XtraGrid is like a navigator. Here's a hypothetical example; ignore the specific use case:

```
OrderId|OrderDate|DateShipped
123| 2017-05-01|<null>         <- assume this is the focused row
456| 2017-05-02|2017-05-04
```

and the VerticalGrid displays the OrderDetail:

```
OrderId
OrderDate
Item
Price
DateShipped
```

When `DateShipped` is changed in the VerticalGrid, the underlying item in the `List<T>` is updated; however, the XtraGrid does not visibly reflect the change until focus leaves the row: an order-date for OrderId 123 doesn't appear in the XtraGrid filling the `<null>` cell until focus in the XtraGrid moves to the next row (by the user clicking on it or using keyboard).

Is there a setting in the XtraGrid that causes it to be immediately refreshed when a property in the bound object is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but what you are searching is the method `RefreshData()` of the active grid view (not the grid control itself) or - if you know the row handle: `RefreshRow(rowHandle)`